# URLEncoded HttpPost with nested parameters

Tags: android, apache, http, networking

how to post nested parameters using httppost with urlencoding?for example

```
{
     "album": {
         "photos":[
             {"id":"1"},
             {"id":"2"},
             {"id":"3"}
         ]
     },
     "name":"jhon",
     "uid":"abc@gmail.com",
     "pwd":"password"
}
```

how to post the "album" parameters. name,uid,pwd are basic nameValuePairs.

Comment: [JSON parsing](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go ahead and create json object and then send it as follows

```
JsonObject jsonObject = /** Create your json Object **/
```

And then use it to post to the server

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
URL url = //Your URL HERE 
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
wr.flush();
wr.close();

conn.connect();
```

Comment: i am sending every thing as namevalve pairs.so for album i should make a json object convert it to string and then send it as name value pair???

Comment: IMO you cannot send the data which you showed in your question as name value pair, so better make json object and send the jsonstring to webserver as raw data

Comment: ok thank you. but does that mean the sever side has to be changed to accept JSON object instead of namevalue pairs?

Comment: Yes..use postman rest client chrome plugin to check if the question you posted is possible using that, if yes then it would be possible from android. Else you have to change server code